# MediaRecorder not workig for Android 5.1.1 on Samsung A8 device

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

i'm recording voice calls from my android application, every thing is working as expected but when i test it on Samsung A8 under Android 5.1.1 i get an illegal state exception , here is my code :

```
public MediaRecorder startRecordCall(String contactName, String contactE164Phone, String callType, Date callTime){
    if (!isRecording){
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ancare_service_recording_started, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            extractRecordingSettings();
            pCurrentAudioVolume = pAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            int pMaxVolume = pAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            int vol = pMaxVolume;
            switch (pAudioVolume) {
                case 0:
                    vol = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    vol = (pMaxVolume / 2) + 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    vol = pMaxVolume;
                    break;
            }
            pAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, vol, 0);
            File currentRecordFile = MyStorage.makeRecordFile(contactName, contactE164Phone, callType, callTime);
            pMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            pMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            pMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(pAudioFormat);
            pMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(currentRecordFile.getPath());
            pMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(pAudioCodec);
            pMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(pAudioDuration * 1000);
            pMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(pAudioSize * 1024);
            pMediaRecorder.prepare();
            pMediaRecorder.start();
            pCurrentRecordStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            pCurrentObserver = new RecordObserver(this, currentRecordFile.getAbsolutePath());
            pCurrentObserver.startWatching();
            isRecording = true;
        }catch (IllegalStateException isex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ancare_service_recording_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isRecording = false;
            if(pMediaRecorder != null){
                pMediaRecorder.release();
                pMediaRecorder = null;
            }
        }catch(IOException ioex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ancare_service_recording_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isRecording = false;
            if(pMediaRecorder != null){
                pMediaRecorder.release();
                pMediaRecorder = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return pMediaRecorder;
}
public void stopRecordCall(){
    if(isRecording){
        long callDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pCurrentRecordStartTime;
        pCurrentObserver.setCallDuration(callDuration);
        pMediaRecorder.stop();
        pMediaRecorder.release();
        pMediaRecorder = null;
        isRecording = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ancare_service_recording_succeeded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, pCurrentAudioVolume, 0);
    }
}
```

is there any thing that changed on android 5.1.1 or it's coming from my code,

Comment: did this code worked on other mobiles with same OS level?

Comment: yes on Samsung J5 under Android 5.1.1 , i suspect that Samsung A8 has some extra stuff that behave differently, but this is not all, it is not failing all the time, some tries worked well !! Samsung A8 is a new device i am curious how this is failing and why

Comment: check the docs in dev site which states that "illegalStateException" in mediaPlayer is often caused because of malformed paths(audio/video) so check that path is correct or not

Comment: path are made absolute and working very good in every device i tested even under android 5.1.1 i checked that in debug mode step by step paths are well formed, the order in wich i call all MediaRecorder methods is correct according to the documentation but i still have that exception under that device !

Comment: here is the path resulting from code above : /data/data/ma.altaiir.ancare/files/records/INCONNU&555/O&20160120113849.3gp

Comment: extract this file and play the file in its default player(Samsung A8 device) and lets check whether it could play in that or not

Comment: yes it's played every where